# Does making a vow/offering to god unintentionally count?

Tags: gods

I make promises and offerings of things I cannot give to god because of my anxiety and fear. I have very bad anxiety and deal with intrusive thoughts.

I don’t do it in front of a temple or an Idol just in my head. Does this still count?

Comment: I have messed up with intentions also, trying to do something properly in a religious way then unable to, because of unexpected practical life situations coming up or stress or not enough time etc. Happens to best of folks. I think it does count, and best is to just try again ? Eventually we get it right 